# SQL Server 2008 R2 tempdb files configuration

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

On sql server 2008 r2 how do I check that tempdb files are configured for one data file per physical processor core? I have been looking on SQL Server Studio screens, but I haven't been able to find where can I find that information. Is this one of those situations where you need to run a script to find out the configuration, or can I find the data on SQL Server Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the files configured for a particular database, right click on the database, select `Properties` and then the information you need should be in the `Files` tab on the properties screen.

I'm not sure the TempDB -> 1 file per physical core / cpu thing actually has any basis in reality however. There's probably a bunch of other things that make a bigger performance difference, such as the nature of the disks TempDB is hosted on and what they happen to be shared with.

Comment: I believe the one TEMPDB file per cpu/core was a best practice recommendation for SQL 2005 and ealier but I don't know if it is for SQL 2008 and 2008R2.